# Datatables plugin: Pagination not correct after draw onclick

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

Now I inprogress to create a datatable for search result. So there will be search form like below:

```
<form id="">
  Colour: <input id="colour" type="text" />
          <a href="#" class="btn submit_search">Submit</a>
</form>
```

So when user submit this form with this, the list will shown up inside datatables. Below is my code calling database and display the result into the datatables:

```
var myTable = $('#myTable').DataTable();

$('.submit_search').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: myURL,
        data: myData,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            // here the search working great
            // there is total of 100 data from the search, but I only pass 25 (TOP 25)
            //
            var json = $.parseJSON(data);
            data.draw = parseInt(json.draw);
            data.recordsTotal = parseInt(json.recordsTotal); // total 100 pass here
            data.recordsFiltered = parseInt(json.recordsFiltered); // total 100 pass here
            data.data = json.searchData;

            myTable.clear().draw();
            myTable.rows.add(data.data).draw();
        }
    });
});
```

From code above, all my 25 data already shown up correctly in the table. Except my pagination not correct. Supposedly there will be 4 page shown up below the table, but only 1 page show.

How do I achieve this either using server side or not. Or do you have any other suggestion to do this. Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try setting some options when initializing the DataTable.
For more info, see DataTables documentation on paging. https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "pagingType": "full_numbers"
    } );
} );
```

If that doesn't help, try also including the 'dom' option in your initialization.  If you use one of the styling integration options such as Bootstrap, Foundation or jQuery UI they will alter the default value for this parameter. https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom

```
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        dom: 'lfrtip'
    } );
```